# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.' in sum map str

Tags: python, string, sum

I am trying to do one sum of numbers like this

```
8.10
4.20
total : 12.30
```

But the problem I think' it's the '.' between number...

```py
eur = str(card["prices"]["eur"])
usd = str(card["prices"]["usd"])

print(card['name'] + "|", card['set_name'] + "|" + eur + "€"+ "|" + usd + "$")

text_file = open(path2+ "/"+"price.txt", "a")    
text_file.write(text+ "|" + eur + "€" +"|"+ usd + "$"+ "\n" +"\n")

text_file.close()
text_file = open(path2+ "/"+"price.txt", "a")
text_file.write("total:" + sum(map(float,eur)))
text_file.close()
```

The problem is `sum(map(float, eur)))`

Comment: If `eur` is a string, then you should do `float(eur)` instead of `sum(map(float,eur)))`.

Answer (score 0):

From the first line, we see your `eur` is a `str`. You are trying to convert each character of the string to a float.

```
>>> eur = "12.34"
>>> sum(map(float,eur))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

It's not obvious what `card` contains. Is `eur` suposed to be a list of strings? Then maybe you just need

```
eur = card["prices"]["eur"]
```